# Vue 2.0 - Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined despite defined render function

Tags: vue.js, laravel-elixir

Working on an SPA using Vue 2.0. I'm bundling all my templates with Webpack from .vue files via Laravel Elixir, laravel-elixir-webpack-official and laravel-elixir-vue-2. I've reviewed pretty much every existing question on this, most of which refer to needing the standalone build or calling the `elixir` function twice in your gulpfile, neither of which apply as I understand it.

Full console error:

`[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
(found in anonymous component at E:\dev\project\resources\assets\js\App.vue)`

**main.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
var VueResource = require('vue-resource');
Vue.use(VueResource);
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
import store from './vuex/store';

import Home from './views/home.vue';
import Toast from './views/toast.vue';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/toast',
        name: 'toast',
        component: Toast
    }
]
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes: routes
});

sync(store, router) // done.

import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  name: 'app',
  el: '#app',
  store,
  router,
  render(h) {
    return h(App)
  }
});
```

**App.vue:**

```
<script>
    // App.js
    import Header from './components/Header.vue'
    import Loading from './components/Loading.vue';
    import Messenger from './components/Messenger.vue';

    export default {
        components: {
            Header, Loading, Messenger
        }
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
      <header></header>
      <router-view></router-view>
      <loading></loading>
      <messenger></messenger>
    </div>
</template>
```

And the site loads via a blade template, super simple:

```
<body>
   <div id="app">

   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
   <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

All this given, I'm almost certain I don't need the standalone build. Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong here?

**More information**

If I open Vue devtools, I can see the root app component. Below it is a single Anonymous Component that has `$route` on it. That's it.

**Gulpfile**

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');
require('elixir-tinypng');
require('laravel-elixir-webpack-official');
var env = require('./env.json');

elixir(function(mix) {
  // Image optimization
    if(env.tinyPngApiKey) {
      mix.tinypng({
        key:env.tinyPngApiKey,
        sigFile:'.tinypng-sigs',
        log:true,
        summarize:true
      });

      // Copy all non compressible images to build
      mix.copy('assets/img/*.!(png|jpg)', 'resources/img');
    } else {
      mix.copy('assets/img/*', 'resources/img');
    }
    mix.copy('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts', 'public/fonts')
      .sass('app.scss')
      .webpack('main.js')
      .browserSync({
         proxy: 'project.dev'
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this error usually comes from pulling in the default vue.common.js which doesn't include vue's template parser. If you change your Vue import to:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'
```

Does that fix it?

If it does then it's an issue with your Elixir set up. `laravel-elixir-vue-2` should be aliasing vue to this version if set correctly. You haven't posted your gulp file but it should look something like below:

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');

require('laravel-elixir-vue-2');

elixir(mix => {

    mix.sass('app.scss')
       .webpack('main.js')

})
```

---

Looking at your gulp and main.js file again I realised you seem to have discrepancies between the files you are requiring. I'd assume that this is where the issue is coming from - you likely have the wrong version of Vue or one of its packages installed.

'vuex-router-sync' is the main reason I suggest this as this doesn't support v2 of Vue or Vuex which would likely have breaking changes.

On a side note you don't need `require('laravel-elixir-webpack-official')` within your gulpfile.

To fix things I'd probably recommend a separate fresh install of laravel so you can compare your package.json, main.js & gulpfile.

---

### Fixing image references in webpack

Following your latest comment the errors you have compiling are caused by you incorrectly referencing your image locations.

If you are using the latest build of laravel then you have 2 default options for how you store your images. Either place them within `resources/assets` probably within an `images` directory. Or place them in `storage/app/public` again in an `images` directory.

The first location: `resources/assets` is then handled by webpack, and on compilation will minify, hash and copy these images into: `public/img`. To reference any of these images within your Vue app you simply resolve the path to them from the file you are working in, i.e.

```
# resources/assets/js/components/example.vue
<img src="../../images/logo.png">
```

points to `resources/assets/images/logo.png`

If however you want to serve static images (no hashing, minification etc..), then simply place them in `storage/app/public/images` and reference them like:

```
<img src="/images/logo.png">
```

Comment: Using `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.js'` doesn't fix it, unfortunately. That was about the first thing I tried.

Comment: I added my gulpfile on the offchance something sticks out

Comment: Updated the answer following you publishing your gulp file

Comment: the `next` branch of `vuex-router-sync` does have Vue2 support. That being said, I'm dropping the `laravel-elixir-webpack-official` from the gulpfile and trimming down to what's in the default laravel install and what I use on the front end. When I do this, it tries to compile everything in my `.vue` files as Javascript and hangs every time I reference an image in the css: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../img/beer.png' in 'E:\dev\project\resources\assets\js\components'
resolve '../img/beer.png' in 'E:\dev\project\resources\assets\js\components'`

Comment: updated answer to look at image reference issues - this does assume you have removed mix.copy & mix.tinypng as per your last comment, as these will likely mess with things and looking at your gulpfile aren't required as the default laravel webpack should handle that all for you.

Comment: Alright, that gave me something to go on. The images it's complaining about are the ones in my sass/scss files. In my `.vue` style tags I'm importing my main `app.scss` file so I have access to variables and mixins, and there are a few image references in there that it doesn't like. How should this be handled?

Comment: Your issue is likely that as you are importing the SASS the image references will need to be relative to the vue file, not the SASS file. Obviously this isn't ideal, so you may want to look into setting aliases to the directories within your webpacks resolve object, i.e. `resolve: { ... alias: { 'images': path.resolve(__dirname, '../resources/assets/images')` just add a `webpack.config.js` file to your project root to set new options

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ES2015, you can do this:

```
new Vue({ // eslint-disable-line no-new
  name: 'app',
  el: '#app',
  render: (h) => h(App),
  router
});
```

The `render` is an object property that is a function. What you have is valid Javascript syntax, but it is not the signature that VueJs requires to set up your vue instance.